# How to check whether two paths are to the same file/directory with Boost.Filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

I want to check whether two paths are to the same file/directory with Boost.Filesystem.

For example, "/bin" and "/./bin" are to the same directory, but the following code doesn't work as intended.

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path p1{"/bin"}, p2{"/./bin"};

if(p1 == p2){
    std::cout << "Equal" << std::endl;
}else{
    std::cout << "Not equal" << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this is "Not equal".

How can I check whether two paths are to the same file/directory?
Could you tell me this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [equivalent](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#equivalent) function, since comparison operators for paths compare only lexicographical order.

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I has wanted.